# Fullscreen UICollectionViewCells overlapping during rotation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, orientation, transition, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently developing an image gallery for an iOS project. The project completely uses auto layout.

I have an `UICollectionView` and use fullscreen cells. To keep the visible cell, I'm storing the indexPath before rotation and select the desired cell after layout subviews.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSUInteger itemIndex = [[self collectionView] contentOffset].x / CGRectGetWidth([[self collectionView] bounds]);
    [self setCurrentIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIndex inSection:0]];
}


- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [[self collectionView] scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[self currentIndexPath]
                                  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically | UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                          animated:NO];
}
```

This all works great and stable. But when having the second or a following cell selected and rotating, the first cell slightly covers the current cell while sliding in the new position.

I now want to hide all offscreen cells. So this is what I tried so far:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setHidden:YES];
}
```

And the second approach was to have a covering view above the collection view and then the cells image view in front of it:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSUInteger itemIndex = [[self collectionView] contentOffset].x / CGRectGetWidth([[self collectionView] bounds]);
    [self setCurrentIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIndex inSection:0]];

    JFWImageViewCollectionViewCell *cell = (JFWImageViewCollectionViewCell *)[[self collectionView] cellForItemAtIndexPath:[self currentIndexPath]];
    [[[cell imageView] layer] setZPosition:2];

    if (!_rotationCoverView) {
        [self setRotationCoverView:[UIView new]];
        [[self rotationCoverView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[self rotationCoverView] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [[self rotationCoverView] layer] setZPosition:1];

        [[self view] addSubview:[self rotationCoverView]];

        [[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cover]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:@{@"cover": [self rotationCoverView]}]];
        [[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[cover]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:@{@"cover": [self rotationCoverView]}]];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    JFWImageViewCollectionViewCell *cell = (JFWImageViewCollectionViewCell *)[[self collectionView] cellForItemAtIndexPath:[self currentIndexPath]];
    [[[cell imageView] layer] setZPosition:0];

    [[self rotationCoverView] removeFromSuperview];
    [self setRotationCoverView:nil];
}
```

I tried `zPosition` as well as various combinations of `-[UIView sendSubViewToFront:]` and its siblings.

So how can I hide all off-screen cells or position them layer-wise?